# Pjax not replacing data after successfull GET

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pjax

I am trying to get PJAX working with my Rails app, and they requests are successful as I see the new html content in the response in the console, but the content doesn't get replaced.  I get the following error from the jquery.pjax.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'parseHTML'
```

and my pjax code is

```
$(document).pjax('a','.main-container', {timeout:5000, replace: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well it seems it had to do with the pjax jquery expecting a full page to parse, but I was using a layoutless response from my rails controller, so it didn't know how to parse it.  I changed line 585 in th jquery.pjax.js to the following and it works now:

```
function parseHTML(html) {
  //return $.parseHTML(html)
  return html
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Wiselinks](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks). It is easier to use and implement then Pjax and also works well with forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a jQuery version earlier than 1.8, you should try updating it.

I encountered the same problem, it was caused by our project using an older version of jQuery.
The method parseHTML() was [added in version 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/), which was [published in August 2012](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/).